# R: Using lapply and sink together: create files and store output in list?

Tags: r

In R, I am calling sink() in an lapply() loop to generate files that capture output of a stepwise regression. While it is able to generate the files just fine, I cannot store any of the values, i.e. lm objects, inside a list, as sink returns NULL for each iteration.

Is there a way to, in an lapply loop,  both 1) save raw, textual output of each iteration to a file, and 2) store numerical/etc. outputs of each said iteration in a list as well?
E.g. doing something like this:

```
    some_list <- lapply(1:n, function(x) {
       sink(file=paste(save.path, label[x]);
       some_function(...)
       sink()
    } )
```

With some_list returning actual values?

Answer (score 0):

after you close the sink in your loop, if you store the desired output as an object of any class you should be able to return the object by calling it at the end of the lapply

```
  some_list <- lapply(1:n, function(x) {
       sink(file=paste(save.path, label[x]);
       output <- some_function(...)
       sink() 
       output
    } )
```